# Spring Boot 2 and Kotlin (with Maven)

Tags: spring, maven, spring-boot, kotlin

I want to start a new project using Spring Boot 2 (that’s build snapshots for the time being), which in turn uses Spring Framework 5 (bleeding edge as well). Reason is that Spring 5 is supposed to have [much improved Kotlin support](https://spring.io/blog/2017/01/04/introducing-kotlin-support-in-spring-framework-5-0), and I would like to use Kotlin.

Now the [example](https://github.com/sdeleuze/spring-boot-kotlin-demo) that I find use Spring Boot 1.4.3, and of course Gradle, and of course Kotlin-based Gradle file. To be honest, this is too much new technology for me for a single project. I don’t even know how to add a new repository to the Gradle (Kotlin-Gradle!) build script. I would prefer a Maven project, since I’m familiar with that at least, and brand-new Spring and Kotlin will be enough experimentation.

So, how to do this in Maven? What’s the `kotlin-spring` plugin called there that I see referenced for Gradle?

Comment: if you use the http://start.spring.io/ project generator (switch to the full version) you can choose spring boot 2 snapshot and kotlin as a language. for both maven and gradle. everything is in there. that should be a good starting point :)

Comment: It seems I was fooled by IntelliJ’s Spring Initializr support which didn’t offer me that. Thank you! Care to turn it into an answer?

Comment: oh sure! Glad it solved what you where looking for :)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

if you use the [start.spring.io](http://start.spring.io/) project generator (**switch to the full version**) you can choose spring boot 2 snapshot and kotlin as a language. For both maven and gradle based builds. Everything is in there.

That should be a good starting point :)